# MsBuild: copy folder if one contains no files

Tags: .net, msbuild

I want to copy one folder which contains subfolders to another location using MSBuild. I am doing this the following way:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FilesToCopy Include="C:\SomePath\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Copy OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
      ContinueOnError="false"
      SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
      DestinationFolder="$(ResourcesPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
```

And this approach works if subfolder contains files. But if some subfolder does not contain any file - it is not copied. Therefore question - how can I copy all the subfolders of some folder using MsBuild?

Comment: msbuild `Copy` copies only files. You can use OS command `xcopy` to copy hierarchy of folders.

Comment: Repeat Question ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025754/how-to-force-msbuild-to-copy-empty-folders-in-project

Comment: I have solved my problem using xcopy. So the question may be closed.