# Visual Studio 2015 Ignoring New Folders & Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I add a folder to the visual studio project, it ignores it completely. It didn't do that until recently, and I am not entirely sure why this is. A clean build does not solve the problem, in the visual studio folder structure, the resources folder is present.
[image]

[image]

And in the latest build it is completely ignored.

[image]

To show it is not exuded from the project:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by latest build? Do you mean it's published code.

Comment: Just change the build action.

Comment: Expand the resources folder. Are there any files in there _in your project_? What is their build action? When there are no files that must be copied to the output directory, the build will not create the empty target folder. See [How to force MSBuild to copy empty folders in project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025754/how-to-force-msbuild-to-copy-empty-folders-in-project).

Comment: @CodeCaster Presence of Expand arrow = Files are there in folder

Comment: @Rahul not always, not in every Visual Studio (or am I thinking of SQL Server Management Studio?). Still my point stands: if there are no files in there, or no _included_ files, or no files that need to be copied to output, the empty folder will not be created. OP's question is unclear; lacks information.

Comment: @CodeCaster Agree with you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to click the show all files button below the "Solution Explorer" text to see that I wasn't including anything.

Comment: You're question was clearly about missing files in build and not visual studio. This answers the question of missing files in visual studio but not in build. If you're question was really about missing files in visual studio then it is very poorly worded, shows lack of research and is a duplicate.

Comment: @AshleyMedway You take yourself way to seriously. I posted a question, none of the answers did the trick. I was new to visual studio, and from the view count you can bet so were other people. This is not a stupid question. Go be rude somewhere else.

Comment: @AshleyMedway wasn't being rude, just pointing out that you could have done more research as this question has been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If the files are missing on a build server check the files are committed to your source control.

If the folder is empty, *its not clear in your question if it is or not*, you can either add a `dummy.txt` file or follow the instructions listed here. [How to force MSBuild to copy empty folders in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025754/how-to-force-msbuild-to-copy-empty-folders-in-project?lq=1)

If the files are missing from a publish you need to select all the files you want to publish, and change the "Build Action" to Content.

You cannot directly select a folder, you need to select the individual files.

Interesting post about the different options for build action:
[What are the various "Build action" settings in Visual Studio project properties and what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties)

[image: Files]

**Side Note**
If you want your files to be published to the output direct on build. I.E. the `bin` folder. Then set the "Copy to Output Directory" to copy always or copy if newer.
*Not sure why you would want to do this for css files though.*

Comment: I had to click the show all files button below the "Solution Explorer" text to see that I wasn't including anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer right-click on on each files under resources folder and
select Properties > set build action to content.